# Сравнение массивов С#

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть текстовый документ, в котором записаны в столбик такое(пример):
11123 абрис
,11124 абсент
,11125 абсида
,11126 абсурд
,11131 абулия
,11132 абхаз
. И таких строк очень много, почти 6000. Индексы их начинаются от 1000 до 6666.
Я получаю все эти строки таким образом

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\VS Projects\Со звёздочкой\diceware.txt");
```

Потом я формирую массив типа int, состоящий из 5 рандомных элементов от 1 до 6.
Суть в том, что по этим рандомным числам я должен найти слово по этому индексу и вывести його.
Вот как пытаюсь это сделать

```
int[] arr1 = new int[5]; //Массив с рандомными значениями, представим, что значения уже там есть.

for ( int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
char[] textByCharacter = lines[i].ToCharArray(); //Строку перевожу в массив символов.
int yes = object1.Sravnenie(arr1, textByCharacter); //Метод, в котором я пытаюсь сравнить
if ( yes == 5)
{
textBox.Text = lines[i];
break;
}
}
```

Сам метод сравнения:

```
public int Sravnenie(int[] numbers, char[] ch)
        {
            int yes = 0;

            int[] transfer = new int[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //Беру 5, так как первые 5 символом это индекс слова
            {
                transfer[i] = Convert.ToInt32(ch[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] == transfer[i])
                {
                    yes++;
                }
            }
            return yes;
        }
```

Но в итоге, мне ничего не выводит. Как решить? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: сделай словарь из этих данных и ищи по ключу в словаре, или хешмап. или массив и по индексу в массиве. если слова по порядку идут, вычти 1000 из номера. будет просто массив строк с индексом от ноля.

Comment: `Dictionary<int, string> words = lines.ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0]), y => y.Split(' ')[1])` далее слово по индексу `string word = words[1234]`.

Comment: @aepot Что-то вообще не понял Ваш код. Как и где мне его использовать?

Comment: @aepot Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
int[] numbers = ... // к примеру это ваши 5 чисел
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\VS Projects\Со звёздочкой\diceware.txt");
// разбивка на пары ключ-значение
Dictionary<int, string> words = lines.ToDictionary(x => int.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0]), y => y.Split(' ')[1]);
// составление числа из цифр, не супер решение, но так тоже можно
int index = int.Parse(new string(numbers.Select(x => x.ToString()[0]).ToArray());

if (words.TryGetValue(index, out string word))
{
    MessageBox.Show(word, "Найдено");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Не найдено");
}
```